# DC for fallen tree

Tags: pathfinder-1e, encounter-design

The party has to bring the wagon through the forest. During a storm the previous night, a giant tree fell across the path blocking the road.     They have to get the wagon and 5 horses through the forest but this is the only way. The horses and wagon need to be transported for story reasons.

Party consists of:

Level 1 bard, skald, inquisitor, paladin, and shaman, and a level 2 magus, all made with the 20 point buy system.

What would be good DCs to cut or move the giant waterlogged tree?

Comment: They have to move the tree or dispose of it or overcome it some how. I edited the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No DC is a good DC**

Why is there a DC? With enough time and effort the party will move the tree and the wagon will get past it. If you set a DC then either they succeed and the adventure continues or they fail and you all stop playing Pathfinder because it was "the only way".

Don't make players roll dice just because you like the sound. There has to be a meaningful consequence of failure/success.

Now if, success means they move the tree in an hour and failure means it takes a day then *if* something (goblin attack happening or not, princess eating a dragon or vice-versa, etc.) hinges on if it took a day or an hour a roll makes *some* sense. Or if failure means they have to backtrack and instead of going through the *Forest of Bliss* they have to go through the *Desert of Doom*, that *might* be interesting - better if they have a choice between the *Desert of Doom* and the *Mountains of Certain Death*. However, in both cases they need to know about the consequences and have some way of influencing the outcome because of [agency](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71265/what-is-player-agency-and-what-is-it-good-for).

Comment: Upvoted - unless the fallen tree is part of the plot line, moving the tree is noise in the adventure. Not worth having them roll to chop, move, drag, whatever. As DM, you  can roll (d6 for 1/2 hour to 3 hour time range?) and simply say "It took you X hours to dislodge the tree and continue on your way". Done