# Is what my DM did impacting player agency in a negative way?

Tags: dnd-5e, wish, problem-gm, curse-of-strahd, player-agency

Our party infiltrated Ravenloft in a *Curse of Strahd* campaign.  One of the party  managed to steal a beholder eye from Strahd that he was using to control a group of beholders and use them as his minions. This allowed the beholders, who we previously communicated with, to attack and kill several of his brides and assist us in destroying Strahd's heart. We made it out safely (barely) and the session ended.

During the next session Strahd used a *wish* spell to revive the brides that were killed because he needed them for some ritual and rolled to also banish the beholders so they were never within Barovia in the first place using the *wish*. Strahd succeeded but can never use *wish* again, along with being weakened from its use. The player who managed to steal the eye is very upset with this and feels like their character's actions were overwritten unfairly.

I can see how this might be a little frustrating, but to me, making him waste his *wish* spell doing this is a success in and of itself. The player who did this also has a *wish* scroll themselves that they could use to try and counter what Strahd did if they really wanted to.

Is this the DM unfairly removing player agency, or a reasonable counter a BBEG like Strahd could do?

I've only been playing D&D for a short time (a few months), so maybe I just don't get it.

Comment: Given that *Curse of Strahd* is a specific published D&D 5th edition adventure, I've added the [dnd-5e] and [curse-of-strahd] tags to the question.

Comment: I'd like to verify: Strahd used a **single** *Wish* to a) revive **multiple** creatures and b) *Banish* **multiple** creatures?

Comment: Yes he used a single spell.

Comment: @Intense Yes, that smells of more than a faint whiff of railroading to me. Which is fine if all the party enjoy it but clearly that is not the case here.

Comment: Did this wish happen "on screen"? How was it worded? "I wish these beholders had never been brought to Barovia" seems like a single wish that would have all those results - the beholders could never have been used to kill the brides in the first place and their "banishment" is a natural consequence of them not being there. Still, this is so far beyond the scope of "You undo a single recent event by forcing a reroll of any roll made within the last round" example in the spell text.

Comment: it did not happen onscreen. I do not know the exact wording used.

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered as is, since the matter hasn't been resolved in play (what was the monkey's paw of the Wish?).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] center if you need some guidance in participating to this website! At what level are you playing? Because a character having a Wish spell scroll is pretty powerful. I think that the fact the party has access to Wish too must be put more in evidence.

Comment: I guess, in this case, the players should be allowed to twist the meaning of the _Wish_, like GM typically does when players cast it.

Comment: @TrangOul D&D is not a PVP game. Wish is not a PVP minigame.

Comment: @Cubic but that's what this DM has, in effect, turned it into.

Comment: @Dave D&D is not a game of checkers with equal capabilities on both sides of the table.  I think that's what Cubic was getting at.  What a DM does off screen is outside of the players' remit.  This is a problem player issue. see 2754's answer.

Comment: This question ought to be closed as Opinion Based.  What we have here is the classic "I don't like what my DM did, I'll appeal to the internet to validate my feelings" style of question, which is unfortunately pointless.  We don't play at your table.  You and the other players have to discuss with the DM what went on, what you liked and disliked, and move on.  That you have one player throwing a tantrum (apparently) is also your group's task to resolve as a case of small group dynamics.  The place to solve your problem isn't here among strangers, it is among you all at your table.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that this is still a _huge_ win for the party? Those beholders are still no longer working for Strahd, and you managed to close off his ability to use what is arguably the most dangerous spell in the game for a hostile NPC to have access to. Yes, it didn’t go the way the party expected, but unless Strahd having the ability to cast _Wish_ was something the GM pulled out of his arse, the end result is arguably far better for the party than the original plan was.

Comment: @KorivinStarmast I do agree with you, communication with the party and dm is incredibly important and should be enough to resolve this. I felt it would be constructive to hear others opinions on the matter and honestly it has been.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast The Answer claiming that this is a problem player is a rather bad Answer, though. Rather than trying to understand the player's point of view, it assumes they are a bad person. It even accuses them of "throwing a tantrum," which is something you say to dismiss concerns rather than address them. The worst way to resolve a conflict between a DM and player is for the DM to assume the player is bad. Just like it would be bad to assume the DM was intentionally trying to frustrate the players.

Comment: @trlkly That the player (not our question asker) will not accept that someone other than he has agency (to include a powerful spell casting BBEG/NPC) is a core part of this problem. As I stated elsewhere, I'd not have done what the DM did, but that isn't the problem being asked about.  The wish spell exists in the game. That means that PCs and NPCs can potentially cast it.  Yeah, that can create some serious issues, given how world changing and how game changing the wish spell is ...

Comment: @trlkly Not to mention the point that Dan B pointed out:    *Personally I think your player should be happy with what has happened. Strahd resurrecting his brides may or may not count as DM railroading, but even so, your player managed to permanently get rid of the beholders and that's pretty good for one session's adventure*

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Both of us have previously agreed that Strahd doesn't have agency. He's an NPC, who is doing what the DM wants as part of their plot. So, no, the player is not rejecting the agency of others. They are upset that the DM erased all of their previous progress (including the Beholders, who were apparently allies with the PCs) . They feel their agency in the last session has now been removed. Even if you personally think the DM's actions were okay, that doesn't make the player a bad person for being upset, nor does it make the question about agency invalid.

Comment: @trlkly You missed the part where I said "I'd not have DM'd it that way" so no, I don't agree with what the DM did, nor  how they used the *wish* spell, but that's not the alleged topic.  The "agency" red herring is. The top voted answer's title captures the core issue: **it is not denying agency if opponents use their resources to counter character actions.** Indeed, opponents doing that makes the fantasy world more believable.

Answer (score 35):

### It's not denying agency if opponents use their resources to counter character actions

[Player agency](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71265/what-is-player-agency-and-what-is-it-good-for) means that the character had control over their decisions, and these decisions affect the game world. (And, they need to have some kind of information to make those decisions more meaningful than random guesses).

Both is the case here: the player could freely decide, and the result — stripping Strahd of the ability to ever use *wish* again — has a big, meaningful impact on the game world.

If a goblin shaman uses *cure wounds* to undo the fighter's sword damage, is it stripping the fighter of agency? Of course not. The goblin is just using its resources to counter what the player characters do. Not every action can be an unmitigated success in the face of active opposition.

Your fellow player may feel what the DM did is unfair, because it resets most their direct achievement, and that wish also did a lot more than what you normally can expect to ask of even an off-label wish: undoing multiple deaths, acting a longer time backwards etc, all to allow the narrative of the evil ritual happening to proceed. That indeed tastes a bit of railroading, but it still is a lot different from just raising these brides again with no good explanation and no cost to Strahd. As long as the DM is fair, and allows your fellow player's *wish* to undo Strahd's, I think this is acceptable.

Comment: Now I fully agree. I'll delete my last comment.

Comment: While I can agree in general that using resources to counteract the player's action does not take away their agency, in this situation that resource is not commensurate. Reviving multiple characters and undoing the beholder's arrival in Barovia is at least two wishes, both of which are more potent than all the examples in the wish spell, especially the latter. To use your own example, it's as if a goblin shaman used cure wounds to heal way more than a cure wounds ever could while simultaneously doing something even more egregious, like teleporting the fighter's sword into a volcano.

Comment: @Ruse I agree, and point out that this is beyond the normal scope of a wish, but it really is the DMs decision what a wish can or cannot do. The DM has provided the player with a countermeasure in their own wish scroll. If undoing these effects would not be possible for the player, then yes, this would not be OK. But if the player can undo it, it is the players choice if they are content with all beholders having vanished along with Strahds ability to wish, or if they want to conserve their wish. I feel it is only unfair dealing if it is assymetrical.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin there is an information asymmetry in that the DM and by extension the NPCs know the exact bounds of what can and can't be done sucessfully with a wish while only incurring the by-the-book negative consequences; the players and by extension the PCs don't.  This information asymmetry could result in unfairness.

Comment: @Dave, I agree. I think most of the disucssion here is how to fairly use *wish* as a DM. The core question is if it was stripping agency, and I think that is not the case; the core fail of the DM was to make it too easy to achieve unreasonable success, and I like (and upvoted) [From's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/207380/75095) on how their effort to amend that in an in-narrative, and still fair way struggles.

Comment: What I'm hearing is that you agree that the DM crossed a line and created a problem for the table, but disagree that this use of wish removed player agency.  I believe it did negatively impact player agency since, in a quite literal sense, it took the outcomes of the previous session and undid them in a way that crossed a line.  The DM made a bogus move that undid stuff the PCs had achieved -- that's subverting player agency.

Comment: @Dave I think one could maybe have done this more elegantly but I would not go that far - the player has a way to undo it, if they choose (always assuming *wish* in this case cuts both ways; if not, and it is assymetrical - Strahd can do super-wish to change things, the player cannot use their wish to change them back, then I think it would be unfair.) I think the DM put effort into making this acceptable and have a cost, so I would not call it a "bogus move", and if it crossed a line is subject to taste. You perceive it more negatively than I do.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin It isn't just whether the player can use Wish to undo a Wish, it is whether the DM will invoke some other means of invalidating the players' actions. The DM in this case has damaged the trust of their players by invalidating their actions, then felt the need to metagame twice, in saying that Wish was used, and saying it cannot be used by that character again.

Comment: Whether that invalidation constitutes a violation of player agency is a matter of opinion. But what isn't is that the DM felt the need to justify such action by mentioning unknowable actions, then further justified them, making the players question if their actions even can have impact.

Answer (score 24):

I think the question here is: did Strahd *always* have that Wish spell?  Did the DM decide in advance that Strahd has access to one Wish?

(I'm pretty sure the Curse of Strahd campaign as written does not give Strahd a Wish spell.  It doesn't give him beholders, either, so clearly your DM is modifying things.)

If your party did this adventure, and then the DM decided: "okay, well, I can't have this happen, so I'm using DM power to say that Strahd has access to Wish, and then I'm using DM power to allow the Wish to be much more powerful than normal", then, yeah, that would be pretty cheap.

Comment: to further the point about the player succeeding in getting rid of the beholders, the question also states that Strahd was weakened after using Wish, so the player's actions have even more impact

Comment: Wish backlash is only bad until the caster finishes their next long rest.  After that, all it does is it drops their strength to 3 for 2d4 days -- crippling on a barbarian, but not so bad on a wizard.

Comment: Everyone keeps mentioning removing the beholders as a win. But the beholders actually aided the players. I could see the player seeing that as yet another thing they accomplished being erased.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, actually.  Beholders are usually a major antagonist, but it seems in this adventure they were allies.

Comment: I'm a little late, but although Curse of Strahd does not include beholders, it *does* include a magical item that can cast wish once in a location Strahd can easily access- so that part is at least plausible by the book.

Answer (score 15):

The main problem I see here is not necessarily one of denying player agency (that depends on other details, unspecified and in all honesty unspecifiable in the question).

**The problem for me is that the DM has set a bad precedent of what a Wish spell can do AND gave the players an opportunity to cast one themselves.**

What's to stop now the players from simply wishing Strahd out of existence? It would be very difficult for the DM to argue the impossibility of this action without contradicting their own previous interpretation of it.

Should the players choose to attempt that, the only possible outcomes are narratively deeply unsatisfying. Succeed and you no longer got a story, fail and the players will feel irrevocably cheated.

This is a very deep hole for the DM to dig themselves out of, one that is probably best resolved by speaking to the players outside of the game, admitting the mistake and deciding together on a way out that everyone would be okay with.

The good news is that this new resolution may actually lead to a more interesting continuation of the story than was previously possible.

*As an example: one of my most-fun-to-play characters was a repentant necromancer type killed in combat due to a misunderstanding with the DM, we sat down after the session and cleared up that he shouldn't have died but rather than pretend it didn't happen, he was resurrected and would thereafter consider himself the "holy undead" of the god whose priests gave his life back.*

---

P.s.: All that being said, last I played in Ravenloft was 2e, so this might have changed, but back then the whole setting was about the odds being **heavily** stacked against the party. Surviving intact was considered a big win, and the jackpot, the absolute pinnacle of achievement was escaping the whole blasted plane. Beating a domain lord was never on the cards.

Maybe the problem is that the DM hadn't made this clear enough in session zero. Either way, an out-of-game discussion between DM and players should sort it.

Answer (score 10):

### Player Agency Isn't The Issue Here.

Powerful NPCs reverting player action via use of powerful magic can definitely negatively impact player feelings of agency.  However, that's not really the problem with this situation.

Here you have a player who achieved an almost impossible success.  They outwitted what amounts to a lesser god, defeated scores of high-CR enemies with a single action that had no inherent risk associated with it, and stacked the deck in their favour in an immense fashion.  It sounds like they did this without losing anything in particular (allies, magic items, permanent capabilities), too, unless that has gone without mention.

The super powerful godlike being then permanently loses a capability to roll back some of that victory.  Given that this being could achieve that rollback via other methods (resurrection scrolls, ancient rituals, subservient clerics) this is *yet another win*, but the player is *extremely upset* instead of, I don't know, overjoyed?  Smug?

When I see these two things together - someone being angry when they don't get every single thing they want, and someone who appears to be bending over backwards to give them every single thing they want, what I almost automatically assume is an unhealthy social interaction.  This description is of a type of problem player - the 'has to win' player.  Not even to the degree that most players dislike losing (ttrpgs almost always tell the story of a group that wins and survives, even bittersweet triumphs are rare), but to the degree that even a temporary setback causes ruction, friction, conflict, and various attempts (both out of character and in character) to ensure they win (and usually in a specific way).

The victory outlined as the starting point of this issue strikes me as vastly improbable to begin with.  If a player has problems with part of that turning out to be a false success, my suspicion of what the issue is squarely targets that player.

Ergo, I strongly suspect your problem here is a player who cannot lose in even minor ways without becoming extremely upset, and a DM who is catering to that, and not an issue with a DM overwriting player agency.

Comment: There are more and less narratively satisfying ways of "losing", and as far as I can tell (which is admittedly not much, given the information in the question), this feels very firmly on the unsatisfying end of the spectrum.

Comment: "If a player has problems with part of that turning out to be a false success" in this case no aspect of the character's original success was preserved.  Instead the gains they had achieved were erased and replaced with an alternative setback to Strahd.

Comment: I do not like this answer. It seems more interested in judging the player as a person rather than considering their point of view. From their POV, they lost everything they had accomplished. Even the loss of the beholders is not a clear win, since the beholders were helpful. And it's not even clear if Strahd previously had Wish. And he appears to have been able to use it to accomplish far more than normal. From the PC perspective, it very much looks like the DM didn't like the outcome of last session and overwrote it. Of course that is upsetting.

Comment: When you lose in a game, you generally want it to be the player's fault. Not something the DM decided after the session was over, giving no one else any input. And false successes are a hard thing to handle, since it effectively requires lying to the players, and people don't like liars. And while I can think of many ways to accomplish it, having the success overwritten between sessions is not great. It should feel like a natural part of the game that it happened.

Answer (score 9):

## We lack information to answer this.

Some of the things that stem from your question are suspicious, but none can yield a definitive answer without knowing the whole picture.

### Your DM is obviously running a modded version of Curse of Strahd

By the book, Curse of Strahd is supposed to span levels 1 through (at most) 10. This is not the levels where you fight groups of beholders, so I guess that's at least something that was changed. Strahd by-the-books is designed to be a threat for lvl 10 adventurers, not for whatever lvl you are if you are supposed to fight a group of CR13 monsters, so your DM surely also have made Strahd stronger to match the PCs.

This could be considered a bad DM move if players joined to play the "normal" Curse of Strahd campaign and haven't been made aware that there would be modifications, although so far it has little to do with railroading.

### Your DM probably could have better handled what information they gave the party

How did you know brides have been brought back? If your DM simply dumped you the info at the beginning of the next session, then that's clumsy: unless the spell is cast right in front of the PCs there is no reason for them to know a wish has been used.

I can picture only a few reasons for your DM to tell you that:

- they assume you are going to whine if later on you find out brides are back in shape. Would they be right to assume that? I have no idea.
- they want you to have something to celebrate about (getting rid of Strahd's wish)

If the intent was pure railroading, it would have been easier to keep everything hidden.

### Your DM seems to have trouble setting boundaries

"Players have agency" doesn't mean "PCs will always get the exact result their player expect": it means player's choice matter, and that's all. Some things may still not happen as they want, and that's most of the time what is expected in a tabletop RPG.

The impression I have reading your question is that players came up with a crazy plan and the DM made efforts to roll with it without pointing at all its issues, but later on regretted to have gone too far and roll-backed some of the consequences.

### The portrayal they gave of Strahd is not what I am used to

I know there isn't a "one true correct way to roleplay Strahd", but still in my book one of his traits of personality is that he doesn't care about most people, including his brides. Using his only wish to bring them back doesn't look like something this guy would do.

Answer (score 5):

### Player Agency and Rule 0

The DM's role is not to win, it is to create an adventure for you to experience. This necessarily means creating obstacles to overcome, and will to some degree mean interventions contrary to Character goals and aspirations.

If your DM had started the next session with, "last session was fun, but the events didn't happen, I can't come up with a good continuation from what happened, so we'll do a re-do", that would have been fair - admitting limitations and working around them is a key part in being human.

What your DM did instead is to employ an in-game quasi-reasonable (magic is magic, the Wish spell is explicitly the most powerful available, and Strahd is Strahd) way to do the the above, without actually undoing the last session. He also added in the "no more Wishes", sort of like a covenant not to use that particular deus ex machina again, while still allowing your success to remove the Beholders from the picture.

It sounds to me like you think you players are playing to win against the DM, and your DM just cheated you out of a victory. That is not what roleplaying is about, you play for the adventure, to create a story, and to let your character achieve their goals. And the DM is there to help you achieve those things, not to defeat you.

#### Are you certain those are the total and exact effects of the Wish?

To quote the spell description:

> [T]he greater the wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes wrong.

I don't know about your DM, but if it were me, I'd probably have punished Strahd further than "just" keeping him from using Wish again.

Perhaps a wording like "I wish I never got that Beholder eye in the first place, so the Beholders weren't here to kill my brides."

Presto! Time itself is reset, for everyone except Strahd and the PCs, to before Strahd got the eye. Whoops, this was also before Strahd got a couple of other artifacts/whatnot needed for the ritual, so now he has to reacquire them, with the PCs active and working against him, possibly with a weaker version of Strahd (perhaps missing some equipment or other resource).

At some point, perhaps some emissary or priest of the Morninglord could tell the PCs that they are "chosen by the Morninglord", to explain why they were exempt from the Wish spell.

Just as an example.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, this was bad DMing

Your DM used the unlimited power of fiat to override actions taken by the players, and - worse - did so off-camera.

Probably they messed up by introducing the Beholder eye in the first place, and are trying to roll back a mistake. We've all been there as GMs, but wishing away things that happened is a very bad way of dealing with it. If the DM really feels that they need to reverse what happened, instead of abusing their fiat powers they should have *talked to the players*.

Although, having run *Curse of Strahd* myself, I don't see that what happened was disastrous enough to need your DM to pull the "reset" lever, and they would have been better to figure out how to roll with the unexpected success of the players in this encounter.

Comment: You might want to add in that the players Should Not Know that Strahd can't cast the wish again, as it happened off screen. It's well beyond their info range, other than meta gaming.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, as wish shouldn't be able to do that.

The closest reliable effect it has is to emulate one 8th level spell, not to resurrect brides en masse and kill a bunch of beholders- that's an arbitrary success on a wish. The DM made a custom ability which deletes a bunch of party resources (the beholders) and resurrects dead NPCs. He essentially erased the content of an entire session with a made up resource and weakness.

And it is made up. Strahd doesn't have wish in the original stat block. You know how stores often pump up the price before a sale enough so that it's actually more expensive than usual in a sale despite a discount? If your DM is arbitrarily granting beyond level 9 spells to Strahd, he's already massively buffed. How can you have any real trust he's actually weaker? He could pull out a miracle and do the same again next session.

Comment: Wish technically can do the effects in the question, but at the penalties of maybe never casting it again (which happened), and stat penalties (which also happened), and whatever the monkey's paw effect is, which it seems OP doesn't have details for. Honestly, this seems like a premature question until the experience with Strahd is over.

Comment: Players have too a Wish spell scroll.

Comment: If you read the wish spell's description, it relies on the DM to adjudicate the actual result and the risks for anything other than the listed features. It is pretty wide open, all said and done, if one is willing to accept the risk of not casting it again.

Comment: Yes, I said the closest reliable effect, and that they gave themselves an arbitrary success. As a GM, sure, you can say the monkey paw effect doesn't happen and you just succeed fully.

Comment: Beholders aren't supposed to be in Curse of Strahd either, this group is very obviously playing some sort of modified campaign and are quite likely much higher level so buffed up Strahd is not "made up" (what does that even mean? The whole campaign is made up by the DM if you think about it) but to be expected.

Answer (score -1):

This is an abuse of power that does subvert player agency; by having a single *Wish* perform functions well beyond those within the spell description this DM has crossed a line.

> Is this the DM unfairly removing player agency, or a reasonable counter a BBEG like Strahd could do?

First, let's handle whether it removed player agency.  This action definitely interacts with player agency.  Strahd's *Wish* undid two major outcomes of the previous session.  Undoing/revoking the outcomes of sessions just by DM say-so is a canonical example of the DM messing with player agency; note that the wish happened off screen so the action and all impacts of it were created and adjudicated without any involvement from the players.  However this does not address whether it was a *fair* manipulation of player agency; NPCs do things off screen that affect the  PCs all the time.

If the wish was established prior to the DM deciding to use then, in a letter of the rules way, Strahd's making this wish is technically legal; wishes can do any thing the DM deems feasible.  The unfairness comes in to play in that the DM and by extension the NPCs know what the limits of wish are, and what potential negative consequences might come from any particular wish.    Players do not know this; if they a non-sanctioned wish they'll have to deal with unknown and unpredictable consequences.  Because of this information asymmetry, DMs have a special responsibility in how they handle wishes.

By the book, one of the standard uses is to replicate the effects of a single spell.  If the DM were to have an NPC use a wish for one of these standard applications, there would be no issue -- everyone has access to the same information.  However in this case, the DM invoked a wish that has multiple disparate effects.  There are no "mass revival" spells that could replicate the effect of reviving multiple wives; all similar resurrection spells act on a single individual.  Similarly, there is not a "mass banishment" spell; *Banishment* acts on a single creature.  Finally, this DM combined two completely independent wishes into single one ("I wish my wives were revived **and** the beholders are banished").  Furthermore the effects of the wish seem specifically tailored to undo exactly the main outcomes of the earlier session rather than being obviously based on Strahd's in-character motivations and approach.  Although they applied the by-the-book negative side effects, having the DM decide in isolation that this mutli-faceted wish can be formulated and adjudicated with merely by the book negative side effects moves this into the realm of arbitrary DM fiat.

I wasn't at the table, and I can't read the DM's mind, but this is exactly the kind of behavior I could see a DM do in order to force a particular outcome -- in this case ensuring that Strahd can proceed with the plan laid out in the DM's prep.  Therefore, player's *feelings* of being railroaded are completely justified. However, it may be a case of a DM looking for the best way for the NPC to recover from the setback.  However, this compatibility is not proof of intentional overreach; instead this may be a case of the DM clumsily trying to recover from an unanticipated outcome.

Therefore I do believe it is warranted to have an out of character discussion with the DM about how this use of a *single* wish spell can produce so many disparate effects that undid the outcomes of a previous session was perceived to subvert player agency and erase the other player's monumental success without any way for the PCs to affect that outcome.

To summarize: DMs have a special responsibility with NPC wishes.  Since they both construct and adjudicate the wish, DMs need to be careful with how they use non-standard NPC wishes so that the world the PCs experience is not (perceived as) completely arbitrary.  This particular wish undid outcomes of a previous game session -- this clearly impacts player agency, and the wish went outside the bounds of a single formulatable wish (it's arguably 2 wishes).  Together these features have led to a problem for at least one person at the table.  Therefore it is worth hashing why/how this Wish came to pass and how to navigate this kind of powerful magic going forward.

Comment: I can't help but think that the DM's move has established that a wish like "I wish for a sable fur coat *and* a light blue convertible *and* a yacht *and* the deed to a platinum mine..." would be a valid wish in this campaign world.

Comment: Recall that the players has access to Wish too.

Comment: @Eddymage why is this signficant? Are claiming that two wrongs (in this case abusing the extent of a wish spell by allowing it to subsume an arbitrary number of clauses) make a right?

Comment: No, I mean that the players too have a lot of power in their hands, given by the same DM (although I disagree with your answer).

Comment: @Eddymage I still don't see why/how providing the PCs with a wish mitigates the fact that the DM unrolled almost all of the players' actions from the previous session with a single wish.

Comment: They can use the *Wish* spell to counter Strahd's wish, simply. And the DM's usage of *Wish*  does not conflict with the rules or with the spell description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147372/discussion-between-dave-and-eddymage).

Comment: "I wish the beholders had never been here in the first place" is a perfectly legit wish that achieves both since it were the beholders that killed the brides

Answer (score -1):

#### Honestly, no-one can properly answer your question.

This is because it requires addressing 2 layers of opinion:

1. What exactly *is* player agency?
2. Do the DM's actions encroach upon that defined ability?

###### What about the Wish itself?

Any time someone uses Wish for anything beyond casting another spell of 8th level or lower, there is to be an unintended effect (often called a monkey's paw), which can be unexpected, hindering, or even harmful to the one wishing. Normally, the extent of the effect is up to the DM, but when the DM is the one using wish in this way, they can very easily adopt the mindset of "I must win", and as a result either apply no such effect, or make it unimpactful.

## So, here is my advice:

Talk to your DM away from the game, and calmly remind them about the monkey's paw. Offer the following: that your table as a whole approach a social media forum where you can gather numerous opinions (such as here, Reddit, Discord, etc.), where your DM then shares the exact wording of Strahd's Wish, and asks what the monkey's paw should be in this case.

Then, your DM chooses an option from among the top answers without saying which specifically.

This way, the DM can try to avoid the "I must win" attitude, your group can know that the spell is being treated the same in your DM's hands, and your group can also avoid the "I must win" attitude, since none of you would be trying to dictate the consequences.

Comment: -1, for all we know the DM has already thought up of consequences for Strahd even if he  didn't deem it necessary to share it with the players just yet. Not to mention that this is suggesting basically telling the DM that OP considers him too stupid to come up with a plot point on his own and needs to consult with random people on the internet.

Comment: @AnnaAG 1: If the DM has already thought up good consequences, they are free to ignore outside advice. 2: This is telling the DM that they have damaged OP's trust, not that OP considers them stupid.

Comment: @AnnaAG Further, that said DM felt the need to tell the players that 1: Strahd cast Wish, and 2: that he can't cast it again, is clearly a justification for cancelling their prior success behind the scenes. Such actions are typically the result of someone inexperienced (where outside advice is helpful), or someone competing (where outside advice is needed).